# how to convert the value of int to a hexadecimal value and assign it to a variable?

Tags: c, int

I have a variable:

```
int a = 10;
```

I want to convert it to a hexadecimal value with `0x` in front of `10` as: `0x10`, and assign it to other variable, how to convert it?

Comment: So, you want to convert `10` to `0x10` which is `16`?

Comment: hello, yes, I want to convert 10 to 0x10, is there a way to do that_

Comment: what do you mean by assign ? do you want 0x10 to be assigned to another value ?

Comment: yes, first convert 10 to 0x10, and then assign the 0x10 to another variable

Comment: Do you want to convert 10 to 16 ,11 to 17,...   or 10 to a, 11 to b ,...  ?

Comment: first please edit the post and clarify what you really want precisely. As you say that you want to convert decimal 10 to 0x10. this cannot be said as hexadecimal conversion. hexadecimal equivalent of decimal 10 is 0xa....so please describe specifically. then definitely you will get proper help

Answer (score 3):

Use [`snprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

```
char buf[128];
snprintf(buf, 128, "0x%d", a); // buf = "0x10"
```

Then read it back using `sscanf()`:

```
unsigned int new_a;
if (1 == sscanf(buf, "0x%X", &new_a))
{
}
```

Comment: I hardly doubt that this is the solution the user wants. He doesn't want the value represented but assigned.

Comment: @Zeta, how is that not assigned to `hex_of_a`?

Comment: I do not want to print out, I want to convert 10 to 0x10

Comment: @user2131316: So you want to convert `10` to `0x10 == 16`, right?

Comment: @user2131316, this does not print it out but stores it in `hex_of_a`.

Comment: @hmjd: It stores it as a _string_. OP wants to assign it to a variable, probably an `int`.

Comment: @Zeta, that is not clear from the question. I guess we are both making assumptions.

Comment: That's half of a solution -- it requires scanning it back.

Comment: yes, sorry, I did not make it clear, first convert 10 to 0x10, and assign it to U8 variable

Answer (score 2):

If your attempt is to reinterpret a decimal as hex, the problem means re-evaluating the polynomial `A = a*10^n + b*10^(n-1) + ... + c` to `B=a*16^n + b*16^(n-1) + ... + c` as in

```
     1 1 2 3  = 1*1000 + 1 * 100 + 2 * 10 + 3
(0x) 1 1 2 3  = 1*4096 + 1 * 256 + 2 * 16 + 3 (=4387 dec)
```

Find the coefficients with repeated modulo and divide by 10, and add the results multiplied with the proper power of 16. (implements with shifting).

Comment: The requirement of storing to U8 simplifies this a bit, as this restricts the number of coefficients to 2. E.g. number '100' in dec does not fit anymore in U8 as hex.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of representation. You can easily represent your decimal value as hex by

```
print("0x%x", a);
```

Which will print out `0xa` in your particular case. For `C` it is insignificant if you have 0xa or 10 or 012.